# Deploying Vue Cli 3 SPA with Laravel backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I have a Vue Cli 3 SPA application which makes api calls to a Laravel Backend. I've created a LEMP droplet on DigitalOcean, and I've cloned the two projects in the `/var/www/html` directory. `api/` for the backend, `web/` for the frontend. I've configured nginx root to `web/dist/index.html`. Now, how can I make api calls, since the root of the project is `index.html`?

I've searched a lot. I saw solutions where I must copy the dist folder's contents to `api/public`, and adjust nginx's root to be `api/public/index.html`. But that doesn't change the fact that I still can't make api calls, because `index.php` is never reached.

Could you please advice me how you do it? Should I create a subdomain?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I've tried this according to oshell's answer:

```
# For the vue app
server {
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/html/web/dist;

        index index.html;

        server_name XXX.XXX.XX.XXX # the ip addreess that I have

        error_page 404 /;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

```
# for the laravel application
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/api/public;
        index index.php;
        server_name XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/api;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
               fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}
```

Now whatever I open, it just goes to the vue application. If I try to make an api call to XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/api/something from the vue app, I've got `405 Method not allowed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup two separated servers for frontend and backend. You could make api reachable via `api.example.com` and frontend via `example.com`. The nginx config should look something like this:

```
#laravel.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/project_name/api;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  api.example.com www.api.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;        
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

#vue.conf
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/html/project_name/web/dist;
  index index.html;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;    
  }
}
```

You could also direct all traffic to you index.php and set it up so `Route::any('/')` returns the static page, including the static assets and all api routes are handled via `Route::any('/api/foo')`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it. Basically these are just two virtual hosts? What exactly is the purpose of the server_name key? Is this a name of a virtual host or just unique name for this configuration?

Comment: server_name should be the domain of your server. www.yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com should open index.html and run vue application. api.yourdomain.com should be the api and can be called from the vue application.

Comment: I don't have a domain. I currently have IP to the server only.

Comment: then just use the ip instead and add different postfixes or ports like `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.1/api` or `192.168.0.1:80` and `192.168.0.1:8080`

Comment: I've updated my post with the results of what I've did according to your directions.

Comment: this actually sound good already. your server seems to respond with 405, which normally means there is no matching route. did you adjust all the routes to include `/api/` in the beginning?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/api/auth/login and it returned 405.

Comment: Can you print `Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();` and see if it matches your any of your routes?

Comment: it is also important that you define the correct method for the route, e.g. POST/GET/DELETE/PUT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208855/discussion-between-nikolay-traykov-and-oshell).

Comment: Actually your answer is correct. What happens is, that DigitalOcean creates public domains automatically based on the hosts. I didn't know that this happens because usually the hosts are created from another place. Thanl you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration works for me on local environment - home directory on ubuntu.

Folder structure

- example/dist  - vue application
- example/laravel - laravel api application
- example/laravel/public - laravel public directory
- example/laravel/public/images - laravel api images directory

Urls

- example.lo  - vue application
- example.lo/api - laravel api

```
server {   

    # server name and logs
    server_name example.lo;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.lo_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.lo_error.log;

    root /home/username/example/laravel/public/;    
    index index.html index.php;

    # location for vue app 
    location / {
        root /home/username/example/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # location for laravel api
    location /api {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # location for api images
    location /images {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```